# I want to show description related to name using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner at Laravel, I have two tables and I want to show a description related to the name and I have already made the relation from the model. How can I fetch data related to the name.

[image: mf_facilities_categories table]

[image: sm_facilities table]

**Model Facility**

```
class Facility extends Model
{
   protected $table="sm_facilities";
   protected $guarded = ['id','created_at','updated_at'];

   public function categories()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\FacilityCategory','mf_facility_category_id','id');
   }                
}
```

**Model FacilityCategory**

```
class FacilityCategory extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'mf_facilities_categories';
   public function facilities()
   {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Facility');
   }
}
```

**controller**

```
class FacilityController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
      $data=[
         'facility'=>Facility::with('categories')->where('status',1)->get()
          ];
      return view('facility');
   }
}
```

**htmtl view**

```
             <section class="manufacturing-facilities">
             <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="section_title">
             <h1>Manufacturing <span>Facilities</span></h1>
             </div>
             <div class="des">
             <p>We make every effort to ensure product quality, we have setup 
            integral quality assurance department to monitor consistent 
            quality of whole manufacturing process.</p>
            <p>Advanced high speed production lines are typically equipped 
            with full servo system, metal detective system and quality 
            assurance vision systems looking at each product to detect 
          defect and waste the defective ones in order to ensure no faulty 
          product are sold in the market.</p>
         </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="manuf-fac-img">
      <img src="{{url('')}}/assets/images/manuf-img.png" alt="Manufacturing">
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Looking at `return view('facility')` you might want to [pass data to your view](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: How can I fetch descriptions related to name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can get this way, Inside Facility model change this relationship

```
public function categories()
 {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\FacilityCategory','mf_facility_category_id','id');
 }
```

**OR Inside FacilityCategory model hasOne relation**

```
public function facilities()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Facility');
}
```

**In Controller method**

```
public function index()
 {
    return view('facility', [ 'facility' => Facility::with('categories')->where('status',1)->get() ]);
    //OR from category side you can this
    return view('facility', [ 'categories' => FacilityCategory::with('facilities')->where('status',1)->get() ]);
    //But FacilityCategory hasOne relation with Facility
 }
```

Loop through `facility` in view like a foreach loop i-e;

```
@foreach($facility as $facility_record)
  <section class="manufacturing-facilities">
         <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="section_title">
         <h1>{{ $facility_record->categories->name }}</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="des">
           <p>{{ $facility_record->description }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="manuf-fac-img">
      <img src="{{url('')}}/assets/images/manuf-img.png" alt="Manufacturing">
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

you can have [`one-to-one`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relationship

```
class FacilityCategory extends Model {
    ....
    public function facility() {
         return $this->hasOne('App\Facility');
    }

}
```

Comment: `$` missing like `$this`